# How to build chained filter in django admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin, django-filter

I want chained filter in django-admin dashboard,Please help me to achieve it.
I have 3 models:-
Board, Grade and Chapter.
Initially when dashboard loads then only board filter should appear and after selecting board filter the selected boards all filter should appear and after selecting grade all chapters of that grade should appear.

I have tried RelatedDropdownFilter, but thats just normal,
it does not modify the view part of dropdownfilter, It shows all results.

My models:-

```
class LmsBoard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)



class LmsGrade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    board = models.ForeignKey(LmsBoard, models.DO_NOTHING)


 class LmsSubject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    grade = models.ForeignKey(LmsGrade, models.DO_NOTHING)
    board = models.ForeignKey(LmsBoard,models.DO_NOTHING)

class LmsChapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240,default='None')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(LmsSubject, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

My admin.py:-

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
    'board', 'grade', 'chapter',)
    list_filter = (
        ('board',RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('grade', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('chapter', RelatedDropdownFilter),
```

I am expecting the filter should appear one by one and should contain the filter list of last selectected item.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it, i just give example

In a simplified form it looks like:

```
class Website(models.Model):
  url = models.URLField(unique=True)

class Page(models.Model):
  website = models.ForeignKey(
    'Website',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='pages'
  )
  url = models.URLField(max_length=2083)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  content = models.TextField()
```

And I have an admin panel set in admin.py like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin

class WebsiteAdmin(AdminViews):
  actions = [scrape_website]

  list_display = ['url']
  search_fields = ['url']
```

Now what I want to do is to add a filter to the right-hand sidebar. It will allow me to filter websites by a scraped/not scraped status. And I take that "scraped" means a website has at least one page in the DB and "not scraped" means websites without any pages saved in the database.

And this is where we need to create a custom filter for Django admin. Like many things with Django, it's ridiculously simple, follow my hands:

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, SimpleListFilter

class ScrapeStatusFilter(SimpleListFilter):
  title = 'Scrape status' # a label for our filter
  parameter_name = 'pages' # you can put anything here

  def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    # This is where you create filter options; we have two:
    return [
        ('scraped', 'Scraped'),
        ('not_scraped', 'Not scraped'),
    ] 

  def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    # This is where you process parameters selected by use via filter options:
    if self.value() == 'scraped':
        # Get websites that have at least one page.
  return queryset.distinct().filter(pages__isnull=False)
    if self.value():
        # Get websites that don't have any pages.
        return queryset.distinct().filter(pages__isnull=True)
```

The last step is to add ScrapeStatusFilter to WebsiteAdmin:

```
class WebsiteAdmin(AdminViews):
  actions = [scrape_website]

  list_display = ['url']
  search_fields = ['url']
  list_filter = (ScrapeStatusFilter, )
```

And that should be it. You can now filter a list of websites via the custom crafted filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the built in filter for LmsBoard and define custom chained list filters for LmsGrade and LmsSubjects..:

```
class LmsGradeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'LmsGrade '
    parameter_name = 'grades'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        if 'sections' in request.GET:
            id = request.GET['board__id__exact']
            grades= LmsGrade.objects.filter(board__id__exact=id)
            return [(s.id, s.name) for s in grades]
        else:
            return None # the filter will not appear if the parent is not selected yet

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(grade__id__exact=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```

and then you can define a chained subject filter that checks for the selected grade and so on.